# Is it possible to lock a scene in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

When switching between scenes in the hololens your coordinates gets reset to the way you're currently looking at while switching.

Let's sey I have a picture at 0XYZ when launching the hololens (scene1) and at 90° to the right I have an object that takes me to another scene if I press it. In that other scene (scene2) I have a new picture at 0XYZ.

In unity I get the expected result as I have to rotate 90° to the left to see the picture in (scene2). Unity keeps the XYZ coordinates while transitioning between scenes.

However, if I switch scenes in the hololens, the picture from (scene2) pops up right at my face since hololens is reseting the XYZ coordinates upon loading a scene.

First I thought that all I had to do was to save all the XYZ of the object (scene1) into a Json and load the Json in (scene2) to set the picture there to be placed at the same spot as in (scene1). But since the XYZ gets reset the picture in (scene2) moves aswell.

So basically, is it possible to lock a scene to stay at its position/rotation no matter where in the room I am?

Comment: Aside from loading additively as in @Kalle-Halvarson's answer you can mark game objects as [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

Comment: This would have solved my problem if I wanted my objects to stay between scenes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to have a main scene which is largely empty except for your camera, and then you load and/or unload the other scenes using:

`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("SceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);`

You can keep track of loaded scenes using the event [SceneManager.sceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html). Then you can unload that scene whenever you want to load a new one.

Comment: Thanks this did solve everything. Took some time to find out how to unload and why I got multiple DefaultCursors. Thank you!

Comment: just a question. Now when the scenes are loaded addatively the scenename will always be the first scene. Before I had an IF statement that would happen if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "MyCurrentScene"). Is there a different way to check it now?

Comment: The way i tend to do this is to have a static list or a stack which i add scenes to in a callback from the SceneManager.sceneLoaded event (this event has a reference to the scene as argument). You can peek the top element of the stack to see which the last loaded scene is. When you unload a scene, you pop it from the stack. Glad to have helped!